# How to generate bundle.js for existing react app created using `create-react-app CLI`

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

This question is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46564182/how-to-convert-a-react-app-to-phonegap-app) SO post. I'm using `create-react-app CLI` for my project. It is a small scale web app which I start (locally) by `npm start` and it appears on browser. Now I need to generate a `bundle.js` file of my entire web app so that it can be used with *Adobe Phonegap*. How do I do that with my existing app?

Answer (score 0):

`react-scripts build` should do it.  Add a `build` field to the `scripts` section of your `package.json` file and then run `npm run build`.  Example:

```
{
  "repository": {
    ...
  },
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    ...
  }
  "scripts" : {
    ...
    "build" : "react-scripts build"
  }
}
```

Comment: I already tried this command. It ( `"build" : "react-scripts build"` ) was already present. Doing `npm run build` generates a `main.719b280e.js` file inside `./build/static/js/` (Newly Created). Is it same as `build.js` ?

Comment: Hello noobie. Have you found a way to get this done? I'm facing the same issue...

Comment: hello noobies, have you found a way to get this done? I have the same problem